# MGF of n iid poisson rvs as n tends to infinity

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I am given the MGF of IID RVs as $ e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}$  and am supposed to find the MGF of their sample mean of n such RVs.
I am arriving at

$M_n(t) = e^{n\lambda(e^{t/n} - 1)}$

This does appear to be a valid MGF, however, there is another part to the question where it asks for the 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} M_n(t)$

I am confused if it is proper to have the MGF equal to 1 for 
${n \to \infty}$.

Thank You

Comment: $1$ is MGF of r.v. which is equal to zero a.s. But this is clearly not the case. Use Taylor series expansion  $e^{t/n}=1+\frac{t}{n}+o(\frac{t}{n})$ and find proper limit of $n\lambda(e^{t/n}-1)$.

Comment: thank you so much NCh. So, $/lim_{n\to\infty} M_n(t)=e^{\lambda t}$. What kind of distribution does it imply?

Comment: MGF of $X$ is $Ee^{tX}$. It is equal to $e^{\lambda t}$ iff $X=\lambda$ a.s. So, the limiting distribution is degenerate at $\lambda$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. When will i be as good at maths<sigh>